# Cisco Switch Port Routing

Tags: routing, cisco, vlan

There's a Cisco 3560-24PS-S, and I need to configure it. I'm not a certified network expert, but I have some basic understanding of how the switches and routers work.
The plan is to connect a BMS device to the first fe port (0/1) and then 2 modems from the other side of the building access this device individually via cat6 cables, but they shouldn't have access to each other. The modems and the BMS device are in the IP range of: 192.168.10.x
So far, I have made the first port of the switch as Trunk, and allowed a list of Vlans, and put the next 2 ports in a different vlan. But still the ports can't ping the trunk port. I guess there should be some sort of routing command to complete the job.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
S1# configure terminal
S1(config)# interface fastethernet0/1
S1(config-if)# switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
S1(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
S1(config-if)# switchport trunk native vlan 99
S1(config-if)# switchport trunk allowed vlan 10, 20, 30
S1(config-if)# exit
S1(config)#interface fastethernet 0/2
S1(config-if)#switchport mode access
S1(config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
S1(config-if)# exit
S1(config)#interface fastethernet 0/3
S1(config-if)#switchport mode access
S1(config-if)#switchport access vlan 20
S1(config-if)# exit
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to ping a trunk port"? What IP address you're trying to ping? For this setup to work, you have to configure your BMS to use 802.1q encapsulation, configure VLAN interfaces on it and assign these interfaces IP addresses in different subnets.

Comment: Actually, for the sake of testing our config, I connect a laptop to the port 0/1 (trunk) and one to 0/2 (access). I set the laptops IP's as 192.168.10.10 and 192.168.10.11 and try to ping each other. I guess the 802.1Q is enabled by default in the network drivers. I don't understand when you say: configure VLAN interfaces on it. Thanks.

Comment: Standard Windows network drivers are not aware of 802.1q. You have to use utility for your network adapter (e.g. Realtek Ethernet Diagnostic Utility if your hardware is Realtek) to setup VLAN interfaces. Nevertheless, your setup wouldn't work, as you have to have *different* IP subnets in each VLAN if they connect to a single device (laptop or BMS in your case). Does your BMS support multiple VLANs in the first place?

Comment: Not sure about the multiple VLAN, but as you say, there's no need for IP routing, and all we have to do here is to use different subnets. Right? It would be great if you added an answer and wrote your code there. Although this comment is also a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create ip routing and ping accross vlans, you would need the following. However, this is only viable if the device is your Router/gateway. If you are just using it as a layer 2 switch, this is highly unrecommended, as it will confuse routes... (the simpler answer for this is at the bottom)

```
S1# configure terminal
S1(config)# ip routing
S1(config)# vlan 10
S1(config-vlan)# name vlan_10
S1(config-vlan)# interface vlan 10
S1(config-if)# ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
S1(config-if)# no shut
S1(config-if)# vlan 20
S1(config-vlan)# name vlan_20
S1(config-vlan)# interface vlan 20
S1(config-if)# ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
S1(config-if)# no shut
S1(config-if)# vlan 30
S1(config-vlan)# name vlan_30
S1(config-vlan)# interface vlan 30
S1(config-if)# ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
S1(config-if)# no shut
```

1. This will enable ip routing
2. Then create the vlans to pass data (you have to create vlans 10,20
   and 30. or they won't pass data.
3. Then gives it a name which can be whatever you want, e.g.
   `S1(config)# name IPCameras`
4. Then this creates the vlan interfaces and puts ip addresses on them.
   Vlan interfaces are shut by default. (IIRC)

Also you would then need to set the user devices to talk to the gateways .30.1 etc..

one device would be 10.2 and have a gateway of 10.1 (for vlan 10)
the next is 20.2 with a gateway of 20.1 (for vlan 20)

i hope this helps, and i'll gladly expand if needed.

**My guess** is you are behind a router. (the trunk port) and all you need to do to enable the vlans is to type "vlan #", this enables them to exist, and will pass traffic. Just putting them on a switchport won't create the vlan

```
S1(config)#vlan 10
S1(config)#vlan 20
S1(config)#vlan 30
```

Please also note that your vlans must match what the router is using, or it won't make it to the router.

Comment: Thank you Robert. But my customer asked me to use everything in the range of 192.168.10.x. So, I ended up using access-list and it works now. I limited the Vlan IP's with netmask 255.255.255.252.

Comment: I never said otherwise. But looking back ip's need a Netmask. Also 255.255.255.252 only allows 2 devices. And if that's all you want then 255.255.255.254 is useable. Saving ip's. If needed. I edited my answer to include netmasks